# Why are these MLE estimates biased?

Tags: r, maximum-likelihood, survival, censoring, weibull-distribution

I estimate the parameters of survival data with censoring which is simulated from Weibull 
distribution. The mean time to event was set to 10 by choosing  the combinations of shape and scale parameters as follows: (constant hazard,shape=1 scale=10) and (decreasing hazard,shape=0.6 scale=6,646).

The censoring times were simulated from exponential distribution.In order to attain target 
censoring rate(0.76),different mean of exponential distribution was set. For constant hazard, the mean of exponential was set to 3.1, and 1 for decreasing hazard.

The mean time was calculated when the parameters were obtained in R by `survreg()`: mean of 
weibull= scale* gamma(1+1/shape).

After 1000 simulations, it was supposed that the mean of mean time for constant hazard is not far from the one for decreasing hazard, because their censoring rate is the same(0.76). However, it surprises me that the mean of mean time for constant hazard is 10.9, and the one for decreasing hazard is 15.1.

So I am wondering that if the constant hazard make the mle estimates more biased than decreasing hazard?

The R code is below:

```
library(survival)
n<-100            # the number of patients 
foltime<-12       # calendar time when study ends
simulations<-1000
mean_time_simulation<-numeric()
censored_proportion<-numeric()
mean_time_complete<-numeric()
shape_input<- 0.6   #or shape=1,scale=10
scale_input<-6.646  #or shape=1,scale=10
mean_time <- scale_input * gamma(1+1/shape_input)  
mean_time_censored <- 1  
for(counter in 1:simulations){
te<-rweibull(n,shape_input,scale_input)      # patient times Weibull
tc<-rexp(n, rate = 1/mean_time_censored )   # times when patients censored
t0<-runif(n,0,3)      #study times start
t_end<-t0+te          # calendar time patient death
t_calendar_censored<-t0+tc      #  calendar time when patient censored
it<-c(1*(t_end<t_calendar_censored)*(t_end<foltime))    #  0 = censored, 1 #dead
time1<-(pmin(t_calendar_censored, rep(foltime,n))-t0)*    (t_end>pmin(t_calendar_censored,rep(foltime,n)))    +   te*(t_end<=pmin(t_calendar_censored,rep(foltime,n)))
censored_proportion[counter] <- (n - sum(it)) / n  # proportion of patients censored
model_complete<-survreg(Surv(time1,it)~1,dist="weibull")
lambda_complete<-exp(summary(model_complete)$table[1])
    gamma_complete<-1/exp(summary(model_complete)$table[2])
mean_time_complete[counter]<-lambda_complete*gamma(1+1/gamma_complete) #mean survival  time
bias_mean_time_complete<- mean(mean_time_complete) - mean_time
}
mean(mean_time_complete)
```